# Consolidate similar urls in SSRS

Tags: sql, url, reporting-services

We are using SSRS to generate some custom reports for a Sitecore site, querying a custom analytics table.  The problem is that it is including urls that differ only in format as completely separate, specifically:

- http://www.blahblah.com/aboutus
- https://www.blahblah.com/aboutus
- http://blahblah.com/aboutus
- http://blahblah.com/aboutus.aspx
- http://blahblah.com/aboutus.aspx?parameterX=Y
- etc.

I want to be able to consolidate all of these.  Not sure whether this should be done in the expression for the url item in the report definition (which is currently just `=Fields!URL.Value` or whether I need to filter the data before it even gets to the report (maybe in a stored procedure)?  Any ideas?

Comment: show us sample data and expected result. What query have you try? I can understand first 4 item been the same, but why item 4 and 5 are consider the same?

Comment: You could write a function either in SQL or in a calculated field for your SSRS dataset that pulls "blahblah.com" out and uses that to group on. The next question though is how do you want it to be displayed? Which one is the desired URL format?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, 4 and 5 are the same because most of the query strings are not important for our purposes at this point.  There is one url where the query string is significant though, and those I will need to deal with separately.

Comment: so what is the group parameter ... the domain  `blahblah.com` or the domain plus action `blahblah.com/aboutus`, I mean if you get `blahblah.com/contactus` where will go?

Comment: @StevenWhite I guess it would need to group on blahblah.com\aboutus, not just blahblah.com, right?  As far as the desired format, I'm not sure if there is one, is there a "best practice"? - I would assume https://blahblah.com would be, but that's just a guess...

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - yes, as I just suggested above, it would be the latter, since we need to log individual pages, not just the domain...

Comment: So domain `blahblah.com` can be a static variable?

Answer (score 2):

I would split the URL into Hostname, Resource, and Parameters.  So that you can then consolidate them how you see fit.

You can have a table of hostnames, and alternate names, e.g. www.blah.com, blah.com, 127.5.5.1, SERVER.LOCAL, etc, etc. so that you can then consolidate based on 'like' hostnames (or not) there's no way to automate this without a lookup table, (as SQL will never know that the IP=Domain etc.)

For resources you'll have to do the same for a list of extensions, to again be able to consolidate on filetype.

For parameters, you could even go as far as parsing this into Parameter/value pairs,  and again consolidate on each parameter... (e.g. you may want to consolidate on pageid= but not searchterms=...)

ALSO.. a parting thought... be very careful in all of this about SQL injection, make sure you're sanitising your inputs properly before doing anything.  Because someone could very easily mess up your database (accidentally or otherwise)

Comment: We're only dealing with one domain, but some people are accessing it via foo.com whereas others are www.foo.com, some with http, and some with https.

Comment: Fair enough, I'd always tend toward making it generic.  Rather than hard-coding hostnames in.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the goal, however, there are some inherent problems

For example, normalizing http and/or stripping www is easy enough to do, but some problems still remain.

```
Select Distinct url=replace(Replace(url,'https:','http:'),'www.','')
 From  @Table
```

Returns 3 distinct values (out of 5)

```
url
http://blahblah.com/aboutus
http://blahblah.com/aboutus.aspx
http://blahblah.com/aboutus.aspx?parameterX=Y
```

The remaining three may be COMPLETELY separate web calls

Comment: Hmmm, well, most of the query strings are not important, but there is at least one url where the query string is actually important, so that's a good point.  Maybe I could write a sp similar to yours that also replaces everyting after the "." with "", and then joins it to a separate query that queries for the specific url that has the query string I need to capture for logging purposes...

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment you are dealing with a single domain so you can use that to split/parse your url.

Check partial result on the internal cte to validate the final result.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/WESIV13135)**

```
WITH ini_setup as (    
    SELECT *,
           CHARINDEX('blahblah.com', [url]) as domain_char_start,
           len('blahblah.com')  as domain_length       
    FROM Table1
),
middle_setup as (
    SELECT  [url],
            SUBSTRING ( [url] , 1, domain_char_start - 1) as pre_domain,
            'blahblah.com' as domain,
            SUBSTRING ( [url] , 
                        domain_char_start + domain_length +1, 
                        len([url])) as post_domain
    FROM ini_setup
),       
final_setup as (
    SELECT *,
           PATINDEX( '%[.?/]%', post_domain) as action_end
    FROM middle_setup
)
SELECT [url], [pre_domain], [domain], [action_end],
       CASE WHEN [action_end] = 0 THEN [post_domain]
            ELSE SUBSTRING ([post_domain], 1, [action_end] -1) 
       END as action,
       CASE WHEN [action_end] = 0 THEN ''
            ELSE SUBSTRING ([post_domain], [action_end],  len([post_domain]) )
       END as post_action
FROM final_setup
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]